# Issue with rerender inside <apex:dynamicComponent>

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender, dynamic

I'm having trouble re-rendering elements inside a dynamic component, for example if we have these VF pages/controllers/components"

Page1.page

```
<apex:page controller="Page1">
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!component2}" invokeAfterAction="true" /> <!-- Rerender incorrectly in this case, regardless of invokeAfterAction -->
    <!-- <c:Component2 id="component2" /> --> <!-- Rerender correctly in this case -->
</apex:page>
```

Page1.cls

```
public with sharing class Page1 {
    public Component.c.Component2 getComponent2() {
        return new Component.c.Component2(id='component2');
    }
}
```

Component2.component

```
<apex:component controller="Component2">
    <apex:form id="form2">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="index">
            {!index}
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!incrementIndex}" rerender="index" value="Increment" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Component2.cls

```
public with sharing class Component2 {
    public Integer index {
        get {
            if (index == null) {
                index = 1;
            }
            return index;
        }
        set;
    }

    public void incrementIndex() {
        index += 1;
        System.debug('index: ' + String.valueOf(index));
    }
}
```

When I click the Increment button, the index will not be rerendered correctly if I use `<apex:dynamicComponent>`, however it will work correct if I use same old `<c:Component2>`. Am I running into a SF bug here or is there something I'm missing?

Also, this is of course just a trivial example (because there's no reason to use dynamic component here), in my case I actually need to use it in order to assign dynamic ids to inputfields.

Comment: When you rerender the dynamic component it is getting a fresh new copy of the component via the getter which is why the index is not incrementing

Comment: I think you're right, but as far as I know dynamic component does not persist to the view state right? If that's the case is there any way to update the index variable?

Comment: did you ever figure out solution to this? Can Dynamic Components not work for form editing purposes at all?